# Distort voice with free software?

Tags: sound-design, voice, voice-manipulation

Similar to

[Any free software to make speech sound different without making it "robotic"?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/any-free-software-to-make-speech-sound-different-without-making-it-robotic)

I am looking for a software that can alter your voice in a way, that the output sounds more or less normal. But the result should not have any information about my voice. I would prefer a free software like audacity for that. When I looked for audacity I mostly found sites that suggested changing the pitch. But i want something that really is irreversible. On the top of that I want a free software that can do this (if possible). What are the main-points that are used for voice-recognition? What are audio-effects that make voice-recognition difficult or impossible? Are there free programs that can do this?

I thought of something like this:

In the end you should not be able to differentiate beetween a man, a boy, a woman, a girl, a high voice, a deep voice etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that most alterations can be reversed unless they are limiting, removing content or random.  Additionally, any changes that would render the original sound unrecoverable entirely are likely going to make it not sound normal.  That said, you are also over thinking.  While a pitch shift, for example, is recoverable, a time corrected pitch shift both adds (or removes) data and the person trying to analyze it still wouldn't have a way to know when they had the correct pitch (unless they were specifically trying to match it to you.)

Comment: My goal is to remove patterns that can identify you clearly. You already can differenciate beetween a person and an imitator. I want to remove the parts of a voice that can be used for analysis. I have to find a good balance beetween human sound and unrecognizability, so i want to create a voice that sounds human but could have been created by multiple inputs.

Comment: that's what I'm saying.  I don't think there IS such a balance.  Either it sounds human and it can be reversed to something you can prove is the original speaker (if you know who they are) or it is altered so severely it doesn't sound human anymore.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this? If it's to do many voices in a film yourself, then it's all a matter of performance, and can't be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ladspa plugins for Audacity. That has a bunch of free tools that can help you achieve what you want. You can mess around with pitch shift and add flangers or whatever effect suits your requirement.